# How to find the average of the list elements within a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

```
sweets = {'cadbury': [180,90], 'candy': [190],
          'milk chocolate': [150, 160], 'dark chocolate': [100],
          'white chocolate': [180], 'ice cream': [122]}
```

The dict sweets has different keys and list values pairs. I would like to get your help on finding the average of the numbers in the value list and return the key with the highest average value as output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `statistics.mean` to compute the mean, and `max` with a custom key to get the key with a max mean:

```py
sweets = {'cadbury': [180,90], 'candy': [190], 'milk chocolate': [150, 160], 'dark chocolate': [100], 'white chocolate': [180],
 'ice cream': [122]}

from statistics import mean
max(sweets, key=lambda x: mean(sweets[x]))
```

Output:  `'candy'`

Comment: I was unaware you could use max on a dict with a key - nice solution!

Comment: @SteveMayne You can use `max` on any iterable. Dict is iterable, and iterating on a dict `d` is more or less equivalent to iterating on `d.keys()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy you could try:

```
d = {x:np.mean(sweets[x]) for x in sweets}
```

Returning:

```
{'cadbury': 135.0,
 'candy': 190.0,
 'dark chocolate': 100.0,
 'ice cream': 122.0,
 'milk chocolate': 155.0,
 'white chocolate': 180.0}
```

And to get the key:

```
max(d, key=d.get)
```

Returning:

```
'candy'
```

Comment: You can use sweets.items() to not call sweet[x] everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Write a for loop for iterarting every key values in dict. Then write inner loop for calculating average for each key. First have to set maximum average to minimum float value then if value is more than min value set it as maximum average, until loop ends.